# How to intercept all actions done on a href in website content?

Tags: jquery, dialog, hyperlink, capture

I have a problem - I would like to intercept all actions done on **< a href="..." >** in content and display alert dialog before user will be redirected to specific pages. Unfortunately, my code does not work:

```
$('#description a').click(function() {
  alert("XXX");                      
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it does work in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SNMxm/ need more information.

Comment: Your code works fine. I think the issue is with the selector you've given. Are you sure you want that behavior only for links inside the element with id `description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really using `alert()` in your live page or some kind of dialog box?
Because only alert will pause the page and prevent it from refreshing until it's closed.
If so then you'll have to manually stop the link from executing and then link manually.
Something like that

```
$('#description a').click(function(ev) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    somePseudoDialog({
        someCallback:function(){
            location.href = href;
        }
    });

    ev.preventDefault();              
});
```